# How to fulfill the colour of geo maps in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, geomap

my geo maps image

[image: 1]

in the pic above, one of the county is only colored by a small dot, why is it happen ? How to fix this ? Please help thankyou

I want the small colored dot county can be fulfilled with the colour like others county

Comment: Tableau Maps does not identify the geographical entity as per the global definition

Comment: you have to make sure that the identifiers in your dataset match the identifiers in the map source (which is often not built in to Tableau and, even when it is, won't have identifiers of the area that match your data source).